# When updated windows report viewer from 8 to 12, rendering is not proper

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I installed report viewer runtime 2015 and using VS 2015. Below are the snapshots of problem that I am facing.

1.Earlier 
[image: with version 8]

2.After upgrading
[image: with version 12]

Comment: I remember when I changed versions, I had similar problems; I had to make sure there were no overlapping items in the design view. As for the font: I'd try another one.